# How to decide on which elements to use to make WPF applications layout?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm still learning C# & WPF and try to make my own windows application. I wish i can find a simple and direct answers for my questions about the best way to create my WPF app layout. Please take a look at the image; My questions are:

- What is the suitable controls containers in my situation? I have many options of panels and containers that can define my application layout... But what is the best choices?
- What is the best choice for that changeable part; Page, windows, navigation window? Though i don't want any navigation controls in that part
- how to make that changeable part show certain pages after pressing any button in the right panel? how to link that part with these changeable pages?
- Can C# WPF help me in designing an application work online/offline?

[image]

Comment: That would have been great if you place your question as text not in the picture. If you want real answers try improving your question.

Comment: i improved my question as u suggested ..thank you for your help

Comment: What do u mean by "Can C# WPF help me in designing an application work online/offline?"

Comment: i asked before about making online-offline windows application ..and people here advised me to convert from normal c# windows application to c# Wpf + Microsoft syn framework ... till now i didn't find any option in c# wpf enhance the point of working online-offline

Comment: [Microsoft syn framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx) does not seem to have anything to do with `WPF`. can you link us to that answers?

Comment: here it's
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880527/how-to-develope-that-online-offline-software

Comment: The answer says you can use `WPF` OR `Win Forms` for your application. if you are familiar with `Win Forms` then go with it. About the `Microsoft syn framework` I never used it myself. But I did this kind of sync for a library management software before. It's going to be a little bit hard if you wanna do it yourself. Be sure to try the `Microsoft syn framework` before going on your own sync solution.

Comment: but i read that wpf provides better facilities that normal winforms ..and the differences are not so much ....so can i continue learning wpf?? and what about my other questions answers?

Comment: Sure. Choose which one you are familiar with more. in that case continue with `WPF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout I would suggest to fit your case would be to use Grids to structure your panel to obtain an automatic resizing of the central part and the use of StackPanels for the grouping the buttons together.

As a general rule I would recommend the use of Grids and DockPanels to structure the layout skeleton. The * option on the columns and row size of the Grids are really handy to provide a layout that will not suffer from window resizing.

Here is a quick preview of a WPF reproduction of your layout.

[image]

And here is the XAML I used to obtain this layout (I removed the buttons)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightPink">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Hello World"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!-- Top Right Button Panel -->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="LightBlue"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="LightGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Hello World"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <!-- Left Button Panel -->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="4" Background="LightPink"/>
</Grid>
```